# Does tagging with <tag>1.2.3 also match <tag>?

Tags: support, tags, search

Often you have a tag like [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode), but then it may be specific to your version so you also have tags like [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5), [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode), etc. This can use up your limit on tags quickly and appears messy to me.

If I use [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5), will it also be picked up as [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode), or are tags matched exactly?

Comment: When searching, wildcards can be used. Searching for `[xcode*]` will (currently) bring back questions tagged with `xcode` or `xcode4` or `xcode4.2` or `xcode4.5` or `xcode4.3` or `xcode5` or `xcode4.6` or `xcodebuild` or `xcode3.2` or `xcode4.4 or `xcode-storyboard` or `xcode-instruments` or `xcode-template` or `xcode4.6.3` or `xcode-organizer` or `xcode3to4` or `xcode4.1` or `xcode4.6.2` or `xcode3.2.3` or `xcode-project`.

Comment: The amount of Xcode tags is ridiculous. _WHY_ do we need one for each version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5) to a question, that is the tag that will be added, unless [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5) is not set as synonym of another tag, which is not the case.

Users looking for [questions tagged *xcode*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) will not find a question tagged [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5), if the question is not using both the tags. That is why it is generally suggested to use a version tag, and the generic tag. It is like with Drupal questions, which are tagged with [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and a version tag like [drupal-6](/questions/tagged/drupal-6).

Users can search for questions using a tag starting with *xcode*, thought, by using [[xcode*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode+or+xcode4+or+xcode4.2+or+xcode4.5+or+xcode4.3+or+xcode5+or+xcode4.6+or+xcodebuild+or+xcode3.2+or+xcode4.4+or+xcode-storyboard+or+xcode-instruments+or+xcode-template+or+xcode4.6.3+or+xcode-organizer+or+xcode3to4+or+xcode4.1+or+xcode4.6.2+or+xcode3.2.3+or+xcode-project) as search term; the search will be expanded to include all those tags, including [xcode-project](/questions/tagged/xcode-project).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I mainly find this a problem with visual c++... you need to perhaps tag `visual-studio` and `visual-c++' but then potentially the versions for _both_. Plus tags relevant to what you're asking about like c++, boost, stl... soon 5 can be a limit!

Answer (score 3):

Tags presently are matched exactly unless there is a configured synonym.

Only use specific version tags if it relates to something to specific for that version.